# acceptable performance for new seagate 1T hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, arch-linux

Seagate Barracuda ST1000LM048

I recently wore out a SSD. The smartctl test showed that the drive on this system is exceptionally busy with small writes so I installed this new Seagate HDD that *seems* slow to me. Is this because I've been spoiled by the SSD speeds or is this drive a little off.

I've checked the physical SATA connections and they are nice and tight.

hdparm readings

```
  Timing buffered disk reads: 342 MB in  3.02 seconds = 113.42 MB/sec
  Timing buffered disk reads: 354 MB in  3.00 seconds = 117.94 MB/sec
  Timing buffered disk reads: 288 MB in  3.01 seconds =  95.82 MB/sec
  Timing buffered disk reads: 334 MB in  3.01 seconds = 110.84 MB/sec
  Timing buffered disk reads: 320 MB in  3.08 seconds = 104.04 MB/sec
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal.

HDDs are awful for small reads and writes as the head has to move a lot and the normal seek time is 9.5 milliseconds. SSDs have miniscule seek times by comparison.

100MB/s sequential speeds is also in the right ballpark for HDD speeds.

Laptop 2.5" HDDs are generally slower than their 3.5" desktop counterparts and I would recommend changing to an SSD.

A benchmark I found for your drive shows a reasonable sequential speed and nearly nonexistent random speeds. SSDs still struggle with random reads/writes, but their far lower latency means they are still usable in those situations.

[image]

You should look for an SLC or MLC drive which should have higher write endurance than a cheaper TLC or QLC drive. The more bits an SSD stores "per cell" the lower its endurance. You should look for drives with high TBW (terabyte written) values.

Comment: The SSD I had wore out in less than a year. It's on an always-on mini with Dropbox and always active torrents. Smartctl showed a huge number of small writes so I thought a HDD would have better longevity. Perhaps I should invest in a higher quality SSD. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenBoston: Aside from investing in a non-QLC SSD, it really feels like you need to tell your BitTorrent client to be less aggressive in flushing everything to disk. Let the OS buffer and batch up writes like it does for everything else. (Synchronously writing every little change might make sense for critical data that's difficult to recover, but a BT download is literally the opposite of that...)

Comment: @StephenBoston found on the internet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0psCj.jpg reasonable sequential speeds, absolutely awful small/random speeds. A high quality SSD should have high TBW (terabytes written) value.